# Socialist country with good economy?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, economy

I want to have a socialist<sup>*</sup> country where economy is good enough to have at least one big city of more then million people, that has well maintained buildings. The people don't have to be rich but there shouldn't be any [queues](http://englishrussia.com/2011/01/16/soviet-reality-that-seems-never-existed/) for basic food & clothing. Upper middle class should be able to own a [private car](https://vimeo.com/105422200), whether it's Lada, Volga or whatever brand is popular there.

Beside the [mom-pop stores](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/mom-and-pop-store.html), street vendors, artisans and small family farms all the other businesses must be state owned. No other private property nor [special economic zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_economic_zones_of_China). All the banks, factories, utilities, department stores, large hotels and so on. Every business that can't be operated by the nuclear family with maybe few other workers at most must be either owned by the state or by cooperatives. The management could be either government appointed like in USSR or decided by the workers like in Yugoslavia, it doesn't make any difference to me as long as its not privately held.

The time period is the 70s of the XX century Earth.

Is the existence of such country realistic? Are there examples of real-world nations that could be used as a model?

<sup>* Please note that the term *socialism* has different meanings in different parts of the world. What is described here is called *socialism* in the USA, but in Europe this would be recognized as *communism*. These terms are, in Europe, not interchangeable at all. (What about other parts of the world?)</sup>

Comment: Why do you want a solid economy?  The point of doing socialism is that you don't need the market to distribute goods for you -- the state does it for you.

Comment: @CortAmmon a market system is only one possible form of an economy.

Comment: The answers to this question all seem ideologically motivated.  Capitalism is a couple hundred years old; of course other arrangements could be successful.  I don't know if you're really describing socialism though; you could just as easily be describing "state capitalism" or something else.

Comment: @Casey The OP defines 'socialism' in this case as the state owns everything with more than 10 employees. That specific system describes only a few countries (Soviet Union, China before Deng, Cuba before 1991, etc) and just does not work. "Socialism" in other senses, like modern Europe or modern China, is much more defensible.

Comment: @Casey makes a good point about nailing down terminology.  Strictly speaking socialism merely means the workers owning the company.  There are quite a few large UK employee owned companies competing happily in the free market.  But state owned companies in a planned economy (ie, communism)?  We ran an experiment called the 20th century.  Half the world did free market, half did planned, some that did free market dabbled in some level of state owned + planning, and the results were beyond dispute.  Planned = sucks, free market ftw.

Comment: The solution may be to not require state ownership of large businesses, but instead mandate businesses be owned and managed by the workers directly - a form of syndicalism, and kept small so they act through cooperation.

Comment: I don't think there are any countries that fit your definition of socialist.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees That is an interesting take, since that has never really been done in the real world, there is no one to say it can't work.

Comment: I don't see any reason this couldn't happen.  Make the capitalistic system look crap, something for people to rally away from.  For example, in the US millions of people can't pay for healthcare and as a society US spends twice that of other first world countries to deliver a similar quality service.  A work of fiction could use that as a base, exaggerate as needed, and apply it to other area's of the economy (e.g. State A has government built roads, State B has every road be a toll road with local monopolies forcing motorists to pick a single provider).

Comment: You may want to read Ursula Le Guin's *The Disposessed*.

Comment: @The Forest And The Trees: Where do we find businesses that aren't managed by the workers?  (Unless you're using the leftist political definition of 'worker'.)  Managers are employees of the company, and  they do perform work - much as some of us doubt the actual usefullness of some of it :-)  So they are, by definition, workers.

Comment: @jamesqf In a typical business the owner or owners extract excess value and have the ultimate authority to hire, fire, set policies, and so on.  Splitting hairs about the definition of "manage" or pointing out that most managers are probably also wage workers kind of misses the point.

Comment: F.A. Hayek answered this question a long time ago with the "Local Knowledge Problem", explaining *why* Socialism cannot work under *any* circumstances. The real problem is few people will listen to the answer, and so long as Socialists can leech off any functioning free market, they can continue to exist. The problem with socialism is they always run out of other people's money.

Comment: Just to make a strong point here, in a world with advanced enough technology socialism might come about not as an attempt at improving the economy but rather as a natural consequence of so many things being automated to the point that there's no point in not giving things away to people for free. Obviously, that ain't the 70's but it is something to keep in mind. A country with large swaths of extreme automation might logically be government owned (since the company is basically just a giant machine) and there's no point in charging people large amounts for something made virtually no labor.

Comment: Please note that the term "socialism" has different meanings in other parts of the world. I believe that what is described in the question is called socialism in the USA, but in Europe this would be recognized as "communism". These terms are, in Europe, not interchangeable at all.

Comment: @Thucydides again, depending on semantics, your argument may be correct but inapplicable, Hayek was talking about the fallacy underlying central planning, but that is not necessarily synonymous with socialism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialism (though to be fair, it would certainly apply in the context of the OP's question).

Comment: _Upper middle class should be able to own a private car_ - I think "socialist upper middle class" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - that's called "post-scarcity" economy. Aka Roddenberry's Star Trek. Whether it would work in real life is debatable, as nobody really was in a position to try.

Comment: Sweden, Denmark, Norway have shown how one variety of socialism (the "Nordic Model") can work, and work well. Of course, the moment you have a socially-responsible economic model which works, capitalist-leaning economists will trip all over themselves explaining why it isn't *really* socialism. I say - if it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, flies like a duck, and water runs off its back, it's a duck.

Comment: @EikePierstorff There's always going to some degree be a slight minority of people that have nothing. It's a fact of life. Either they are lazy, unfortunate, living in a poorer area, victim of some recent accident that left them pennyless, etc. A socialist system doesn't imply everyone gets equal pay, just that the government owns all businesses; however, whether that works well at lowering the number of poor people is debatable.

Comment: How doesn't the USSR itself fit your description? Did you forget to mention some other condition, like "it doesn't collapse 70 years later"?

Comment: @EikePierstorff "I think "socialist upper middle class" is an oxymoron." Of course it isn't anymore if you rephrase it like "the more progressive half of the worker class". ;)

Comment: Such a country could easily exist, but it's hard to see it as possible in the 1970s. The problem isn't so much the economic system (which could easily be funded through an appropriate discovery of some valuable natural resource), but the tensions of the rest of the world at the time. For potential example funding, see [**Nauru**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauru), but beware of pitfalls. Also, consider State of Alaska where State effectively pays "taxes" to residents rather than vice versa. Not 'socialist', but might help as model evidence of self-funding.

Comment: Do you mean private production property or all property ?

Comment: Communism/Socialism is really only possible if the need to compete against eachother for resources is eliminated, therefore you'd most likely need 80's or 90's technology (especially when it comes to producing energy)

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner Not quite.  Pure planned failed on many levels.  But pure free market also failed on a lot of levels too, which is why many people in Russia actively support a return to communism.  The "Nordic model" of socially-responsible capitalism was an attempt to combine the two, and arguably has been more successful than either.  The USA has a distinct advantage in the 20th-century experiment too, by losing far fewer people and virtually no infrastructure to warfare.

Comment: I don't have enough info to back up a full answer, but it might be worth looking into Kerala which appears to have the best living conditions in India but appears to be built upon more socialist foundations.

Comment: @Graham The Nordic model is rampantly free market, with heavy tax and redistribution.  It's important to note that free market absolutely does **not** mean either absence (or presence) of social welfare.  A free market economy  is currently (until effectively omnipotent AIs take over) the system that leads to the maximum economic growth and wealth creation.  If you are of a mind to, you can then use taxes and welfare to redistribute that wealth - the Nordic model.

Comment: @Thucydides I don't understand why people still bring up Hayek's argument. Even the first time I found out about it, it seemed to be a completely obsolete argument because it assumes a completely obsolete level of technology.

Comment: Hayek's argument even applies with AI and the internet, because the Local Knowledge Problem is about the *time* it takes to gather, transmit and process information. This is always a finite figure, and transmission is limited by bandwidth. All that has happened with the internet is billions of more pieces of information are being passed, increasing the problem exponentially rather than decreasing it (and curating the information to reduce bandwidth also takes time, and risks deleting important pieces of information).

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner  That's an interesting point of view, because tax-and-spend is by its very definition centrally-controlled, and the only efficient way of spending those taxes on public services is state ownership of those public services.  By definition, privatising public services simply adds extra costs to pay the owners/shareholders, for no benefit to the end user or the country as a whole.

Comment: @T.C. And which technology changes his argument, exactly? I've met none of this magic :) If anything, advances in computer technology have shown us how utterly right he was - it's really a very complex n-body problem with as many bodies as there are humans, points in time and enterprises in general. We're no closer to solving that problem than we were two hundred years ago - if anything, the problem has gotten *worse* since the economy is so much more complex and rich, much faster than our administrative and computing capabilities. Weather is peanuts to markets - and we still suck at that!

Comment: "Socialism is impossible!" "Socialism works every day!" "Socialism can never succeed!" "Socialism is the most successful!" Notice a pattern here? When everyone provides their own personal definition for what a word means, idiotic arguments about who is right always arise, but nobody's willing to accept that their pet definition isn't the only possible one.

Comment: @Thucydides (*F.A. Hayek answered this question a long time ago with the "Local Knowledge Problem", explaining why Socialism cannot work under any circumstances." *)  I literally just finished reading Hayek's seminal essay, and it DOES. NOT. SAY. THIS.

Comment: USSR had dozens of cities like that, so why the question "is it realistic"? It is.

Comment: @Graham I was talking purely about tax and *redistribute*, to ensure that the economic growth and wealth creation are to some extent shared.  Put simply, take some money from the rich and give it to the very poor.  All tax carries a deadweight cost, and all government projects are inefficient, but nevertheless, there are some things only a government can do, such as provide a road network.  But privatisation which brings competition will bring drives for efficiency and quality, improving cost and quality of product for the consumer - like the privatised water and energy supplies in England.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner I'm not sure if you are being facetious or not with "like the privatised water and energy supplies in England"?. I'm in England and the privatised water/energy is most definitely not seen as good quality or value for money. There are people who say it improved since they were privatised which is undoubtedly true, but I don't think it had much to do with privatisation, just technological improvement. Plenty of 1st world privatised utilities which still get regular brownouts today. UKs privatisation just created private monopolies, not free markets.

Comment: @HSharp in the UK we haver a wonderful little experiment with water companies. English was privatised, Welsh is a sort of private govt hybrid, and Scottish is fully state owned. The English providers are constantly rated higher by OFWAT than the Welsh, who are rated higher than the Scottish.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner OFWAT do not cover Scottish water, but it would be interesting to see any comparisons they have done involving Scottish Water, I have not found any. AFAIK they don't overall rank different providers either and on their latest findings the worst providers (objectively) are Southern, Thames and Anglian Water [2022-23 Report](https://www.ofwat.gov.uk/regulated-companies/company-obligations/outcomes/water-company-performance-report-2022-23/). Harder to compare historically but for the last few years Thames has been consistently poor.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Whenever there's a question about socialism or capitalism on here I always get fed up with the trite and blinkered answers which obsess only on the most painfully obvious facts of the matter - namely the USA and USSR.

But the fact is capitalism and socialism are broad philosophies with many different implementations.  Socialist economies can be mixed, and many were.  Often the question hinges on how you define the "[means of production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Means_of_production)". Consider the rise of democratic socialism in Britain.  When the socialist Labour party won the [1945 general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_1945) many industries were nationalised: coal, steel, railways, healthcare, defence, etc.  This didn't mean private enterprise was forbidden.  Banks were regulated but private, along with many other large and small companies.

**The Rise and Fall of British Socialism**

While [full employment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_employment) was achieved after the war, attempting to maintain it became crippling. Job-for-life-socialism was assumed best for the individual and economy, but it eventually led to the [Winter of Discontent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_of_Discontent) in 1978.  [Stagflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagflation) affected many economies in the 70s and was not specific to Britain or socialism; but low growth, high inflation, and union demands created a perfect storm.  British socialism was especially vulnerable to stagflation, given that the Labour party was unable to mediate between the national interest, corporate management, and the workers (as the party had always been the party of the unions).

[Far-left union agitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Militant_(Trotskyist_group)) destroyed the system.  Strikes were so frequent and disruptive that electricity was rationed in many places to a [three day week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-Day_Week).  Productivity collapsed as there were no regulations on when a union could call a strike, or how many union members needed to agree for one to begin. Many amongst the far left hoped this chaos would lead to an even more socialist government... but all it did was give [Margret Thatcher a mallet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thatcherism) with which to smash the socialist system.  She won the [1979 general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_1979), promising to bring the unions to heel and to end British socialism (spoiler alert: she did).

Regardless of how it ended, Britain saw solid economic growth and increasing living standards with a socialist economy from 1945 to 70.  The national debt was an eye-watering 240% of GDP after the war, and rationing was [enforced until 1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationing_in_the_United_Kingdom#Post-Second_World_War)... but by the 70s the national debt had been brought back to manageable levels.  The [postwar consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-war_consensus) was that whoever got elected; Conservative or Labour, they'd not rock the boat.  Indeed, Conservative prime minister Harold MacMillan said in 1957: ["You've never had it so good"](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/july/20/newsid_3728000/3728225.stm).  And he was correct.

**A Question of Political and Economic Balance**

The main issue is how the state handles technological progress.  If government never commits to full employment, and instead seeks technological innovation and promotes jobs when they are necessary, you'd likely see a more stable system over the longer term.  A mixed economy is essential too.  Let the private sector do its thing, while the public controls the "means of production" and seeks to improve its efficiency.

A large part of Germany and Scandinavia's success is owing to their willingness to mediate between national, corporate, and workers' interests.  They engage in a collaborative and strategic consensus quite unlike the adversarial and tactical  politics found in the UK or USA.

Perhaps the biggest problem is the conflict between socialism's raison d'etre of protecting worker's rights, and the cycles of redundancy brought about by rapid technological change.  And perhaps the obvious solution is to make a clear distinction between workers and jobs.  Government needs to empower workers, and yet not be precious about obsolete jobs.

You're basically having to sell to someone that being made redundant is a good thing.  It can be, if the opportunities are better on the other side.  Socialist economies typically offer free higher education, so it's entirely possible.  You need to encourage some sort of idea of cycles of technological rebirth.  If you go too soft (letting unions run amok) the system will fail. If you go too hard (nationalising everything and always spending the profit) the system will fail.

**What Can Public Ownership Look Like?**

Sometimes it isn't necessary to nationalise all industries, simply the largest ones.  Ghana is an interesting example which certainly started as a democratic system, but [unfortunately ended rather bleakly](http://www.nytimes.com/1964/05/03/portrait-of-nkrumah-as-dictator.html).  Nonetheless their leader, [Kwame Nkrumah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwame_Nkrumah), was a socialist who embarked upon many grand industrial projects to benefit his people, quite reminiscent of the infrastructure projects of the [New Deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Deal).  The Volta river project was to create a hydroelectric dam which would produce the electricity to allow them to smelt and thus export aluminium rather than just the ore.  This would also provide the electricity to drive industrialisation and economic growth, leading Ghana to economic independence, which would be the catalyst for a united Africa.

Unfortunately they lacked financing, and American backers suggested they would bridge the gap if restrictions were placed on what could be made from the dam's electricity. They were also interested in importing ore to use in the Ghanaian smelt; on face value because Ghanaian ore was not usable, in reality because they feared an integrated project would be nationalised.

That was against Nkrumah's plan to seek economic independence through national development.  As the project dragged on Nkrumah became increasingly unpopular, and reacted with increasingly paranoid and authoritarian decisions.  Just a month after the dam was completed Nkrumah was overthrown by a CIA-led military coup.  The Americans got their terms, and Nkrumah's dream of creating an industrial example for a united post-colonial Africa died.

There are other examples where public ownership of the means of production (or simply the largest company) has had an overwhelmingly positive influence on society, namely Norway.  In 1972 Norway's government created [Statoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statoil), which was and still is a publicly owned energy company.  The Norwegians however had a very shrewd vision, and dumped profits from Statoil into a public fund.  Importantly only the interest from this would be used to bolster public spending.

This was owing to their concern that spending all of the proceeds would imbalance the Norwegian economy to the point it was dependent and uncompetitive.  This was a concern not shared by Venezuela's [Hugo Chavez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Ch%C3%A1vez), who spent oil money subsidising the cost of food and fuel.

Long term this ended in the [economic and political implosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_in_Bolivarian_Venezuela) of a country with great potential.  Comparatively, Norway is now proportionally one of the richest nations on earth, with one of the most educated populations who enjoy a very high standard of living.  Consider examples like this to be how the means of production could be administered sensibly, and the relevance of the old question: which is more important, controlling inflation or unemployment?

Comment: +1 for informing me on some history in other countries. There's a lot of valid points in this post, and I learned something in the process, so thank you.

Comment: I've been here for about a year now, but this answer is literally one of the best things ever happened here. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Yakk I literally wrote: "Stagflation affected many economies in the 70s and was not specific to Britain or socialism" ... I am very confused by your comment.

Comment: "was overthrown by a CIA-led military coup" sadly this applies to many socialist projects post ww2. I think it's very short sighted how some people assume capitalism is the best as it's still around when socialism has been (and still is) unfairly attacked. "Free" trade capitalism is very good at trade embargoes.

Answer (score 41):

Cuba is about the closest you'll get.

Cuba's economy was artificially depressed for the last 50 years due to trade embargos.  For much of that time though it still had a market in the USSR, its major export (sugar) was relatively valuable, and imported fuel (again from the USSR) was relatively inexpensive.  It wasn't until the simultaneous impacts of the demise of the USSR, the bottom dropping out of the sugar market and the price of oil rising hugely that more flexibility was needed.  In particular, with the dropping of the embargo, the Cuban government discovered that tourism was once again their major asset, and this could not reasonably be centrally controlled.

This flexibility has serious limits though, and prices of many commodities are centrally controlled.  Much of Cuba's population still work in public sector jobs too.  So whilst it's not centrally-controlled to the extent you ask for (>10 employees), it's still recognisably a centrally-controlled communist country, just with a small amount of wiggle room where previously there was none.

The Cuban economy isn't the best in the world, but it isn't in too bad shape compared to a lot of countries with similar size and natural resources.  On the plus side, by many measures it has the best healthcare in the world, its school education system is famously good, and homelessness virtually doesn't exist.  So whether it "sucks" would very much depend on your viewpoint.  If you're Donald Trump, it looks awful because there's nowhere to strip-mine or strip-mall.  If you're some homeless guy on the streets of New York, it looks like the next best thing to Paradise.  If you're a regular working-class person, it's a mixed bag of no shopping malls and much more limited types of work, but a guarantee that you're always going to have food on the table, you're never going to lose your home, you're never going to have to pay for medical care, and you're never going to have to pay for your kids' education.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be the best healthcare in the world by many measures. Perhaps one or two. I've heard you have to bring your own bed sheets to the hospitals because they don't have enough.

Comment: @user3161729 And a general shortage of imported medicines, of course.  OTOH out of necessity they've got preventative care to a level where all other countries come to Cuba for a masterclass on how to do it.  So if you end up with some exotic disease/disorder then you're probably screwed, and cancer is particularly an issue; but for the majority of everyday medical issues you're going to be doing OK.  And of course with good preventative care you might not get to the point of needing a hospital in the first place.

Comment: While Cuba certainly isn't Haiti, from what I understand of it the two largest problems are a [complete ban on private enterprise](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-latin-america-36375807) only being lifted now, and that your claim that Cuba has the best healthcare in the world is [demonstrably false](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Health_Organization_ranking_of_health_systems_in_2000).  The WHO 2000 ranking is out of date, but it gives a good general view of healthcare outcomes by the type of system - at the time it was considered comprehensive enough to not need repeated.

Comment: @inappropriateCode `at the time it was considered comprehensive enough to not need repeated` - actually, the WikiPedia article in you link states the opposite: `Indeed, the 2000 results have proved so controversial that the WHO declined to rank countries in their World Health Reports since 2000, but the debate still rages on.` But I appreciate your point, and stand convinced.

Comment: @ANeves I'm just not reading things comprehensively today!  I stand corrected!

Comment: Cuba's a great example of what Communism can do: the average standard of living is probably lower than somewhere like the US, but the minimum standard of living is much higher. Overall, communist economies seem less efficient but have fewer negative externalities.

Comment: This reads more like Cuban propaganda rather than based in reality. The best healthcare in the world? A master-class is preventative care? Propagandists are not the best source of objective information - Michael Moore is not a journalist. While the embargo by the US has been a great scapegoat, it is not the most significant factor in the Cuban economy - the relative poverty and privation of the Cuban people is entirely due to the socialist economic plans.

Comment: I've talked to a fair number of Cuban immigrants and this is not at all how I've ever heard any of thier first hand experiences.

Answer (score 25):

**Not in a long run**. Sooner or later you will run out of other people's money.

If you really need it, and you want real socialism, not a mixed system like China, here are a few things that could help you make it more realistic:

- Use small country. If they got lucky of having an enlightened government it's easier to run small country then a large one.
- Use homogeneous country (race, religion, nationality). Homogeneous population could much easily reach consensus.
- Recent switch to socialism, if they accumulated quite a lot of capital stock they could run on it for a while.
- Populist elections vs revolutionary war. If the switch to socialism happened in populist elections the capital stock stayed intact compared to revolutionary war.
- Tourism income. If the country earns sizable amount of its foreign currency from tourism, they will be interested to keep their cities in good order. At least the ones regularly visited by tourists.
- Peaceful & neutral. Stay out of conflicts. Socialist countries have a tendency to under invest in capital stock.

**Use small businesses to improve productivity.**

*Companies with less than 10 employees could be private*

You could run  a lot of things with below 10 employees: motels, small hotels, restaurants, bakeries, gas stations, workshops. Heck you could run a hydro power plant with 10 people beside a yearly refurbishment, which could be done by other company. Even investment bank could be run with less then 10 people, just outsource everything (secretaries, cleaning, accounting..) beside your core staff.

So if the law doesn't specify revenue or capital beside number of employees you can bend the law very far. Use whatever works for you best.

Comment: It's already a mixed system because the question talks about ownership and as everyone knows, property is theft.

Comment: @Separatrix The question says that small businesses with less then 10 employees are fine. You could run a lot of things with 10 people (small hotel, bar, restaurant,   store, workshop) that should help with lack of productivity. Landlord who makes a living from renting his building has an incentive to do maintenance.

Answer (score 25):

The evidence from our own history suggests that countries with strictly state owned businesses are an economic disaster. However, state owned businesses were all the rage for pretty much all of history until 1500.

Ancient Egypt concentrated its linen and cloth industries in Pharoah's palace workshops in Memphis. The Roman Emperors owned huge swathes of the state, both farmland and industrial mining, marble-quarrying, and amphorae-making concerns. During the Golden Age of Islam under Caliph Harun al-Rishd, the entirety of Mesopotamia was essentially one big plantation, worked by native serfs and imported slaves. Massive workshops in Basra and Baghdad produced sugar, paper, and other luxury goods. The same could be said with the Gangetic plain during the 17th century under the Moghuls.

So the easy solution is to set your story in pre-modern times. Then no one will notice the squalor of your society, since the whole world is poor.

Comment: Is there a good reason why the system worked in ancient times but not after 1500?

Comment: The 1500 saw some radical alterations to the social fabric of Europe.  Basically, that period is where the primacy of Religion and State ended.  Individuals became more empowered and less willing to just bend over and take whatever the religious/political leadership decided to give them.

Comment: The ancient Romans, the Byzantines, and others did, in fact, have largely planned economies, but the idea that these societies were all squalid and poor doesn't stand up to scrutiny.

Comment: @Casey The vast majority of humanity before the Industrial Revolution was living hand to mouth. Just because the emperor wears purple silks doesn't mean that 1/2 of his subjects aren't one bad harvest from famine.

Comment: Up until about 1500 (and for some, for a long time after) the vast majority of humankind subsisted on that $2 a day or less (inflation etc adjusted to the best of our ability) so those economies still sucked.  That all sucked equally does not mean they did not suck.

Comment: According to the [UN](http://www.unmillenniumproject.org/resources/fastfacts_e.htm), 2.7 billion people still live on less than two dollars a day despite a global system where domination of markets is nearly total.  When you also take into account the confounding factor that modern societies have far more efficient methods of manufacturing, medicine, resource extraction, etc., it's less than clear that the ancient system was catastrophic or catastrophic specifically because of being planned.

Comment: Also, the Middle Ages saw devolution of power away from the state and didn't exactly represent a huge improvement in prosperity over the classical era -- despite some of the "Dark Ages" stuff being overblown I think we can reasonably see the classical era as more prosperous.

Comment: Calling ancient monarchies and totalitarian regimes set before the existence of Marx "socialism" makes me doubt you know what socialism even is.

Comment: OTOH there is also a huge list of failure with free economy (anarchism, like it was with clans, tribes and so on). Also on recent history. But to compare apples with oranges, we need to know a lot more about what are the characteristic of apples and oranges, not just a superficial look.

Comment: @Sklivvz Before the edit, the original question did not ask about 'socialism', even though that was in the title, it asked about state controlled economies. That is what I answered about. Its not my fault the question has shifted and now all the answers are pro-communist polemics.

Comment: @kingledion my comment was about the conclusion from your answer: "So the easy solution is to set your story in pre-modern times. Then no one will notice the squalor of your **socialist society**, since the whole world is poor."

Comment: @Casey It's not as simple a comparison as you make it. Rome and its "related regions" were heavily dependent on coerced "trade" from Rome's colonies, mostly in North Africa, and to some extent various parts of Southern Europe. Middle Ages Europe had little fertile land, with long, harsh winters and unable to keep domesticated animals. A huge amount of the progress of "the dark ages" was simply improving food production to a point where they could finally afford large-scale trade and manufacturing. Most of Middle Age Europe was forests and marshes, and very cold at that - nothing like today.

Comment: To be fair, history also suggests that all kinds of countries with private businesses are an economic disaster. I can't think of a single country where the economy **didn't** collapse at least once in any 200 year time frame.

Comment: @Casey It requires the most expansive possible definition of free markets, to the point of being meaningless, to claim free-market capitalism as having near total dominion over the world. While you can argue at the margins, it is more than a little but of a stretch to reject free markets because people living in oppressive regimes are not all wealthy. If you compare per capital GDP with economic freedom, you will see a significant correlation.

Comment: Rome's economy was VERY similar to modern Capitalists governments.  Yes, it was ruled by wealthy senators and emperors who owned large business enterprises,  but it also had 100s of thousands of small family owned farms and other businesses controlled by freemen.  So, the Emperor might own a very big piece of the economic pie, but he could not just fix prices and control the whole economy because he still had to compete with all the small businesses.   Most ancient civilizations were made of between 10-70% freemen who owned small businesses.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can, but you can't get the answer from us.

Generally speaking economists and philosophers have found that socialism is an unstable equilibrium.  It is constantly being disrupted by the nature of humans, and energy must be continuously spent maintaining it, or it falls apart.  The larger the group, the more rapidly it falls off of this ideal.

Accordingly, there is no way we can give you a path for your state.  There is no path that can be written down on paper, and handed to you with a note saying "here's how to make socialism work."  Your state is going to have to *constantly* observe the disruptions and find the most efficient way to deal with each of them as they come.

What we can do, and many of the answers have done, is show you a laundry list of ways that we have observed socialist (and communist) countries falter.  You can draw from these as examples of what your society is going to have to to combat.  But the actual solutions must be carefully measured against the exact specifics of each occurrence.  Underact, and your society falls apart.  Overact, and you turn into a totalitarian regime that destroys itself or its economy.  Balance is the key, and if there was a way to write down the right way to balance a government, we'd have a lot fewer problems in our world today (I like to think the Founding Fathers of the United States at least got close).

Comment: The equilibrium problem can be restated as the "Local Knowledge Problem". F.A. Hayek demonstrated that it is impossible for a command economy (and Socialism is a command system) to outperform any free market system, and indeed real world examples show the more centralized the system, the worse off it becomes.

Comment: Right. If it was a properly viable system then there would be socialist societies springing up all over the place and taking over by osmosis. People would have been breaking down fences to get into socialist countries. But they didn't.

Comment: @RedSonja And what's really interesting is we do indeed see socialist societies springing up all the time.  They're just small (a handful of people, not a nation), and they tend to break apart relatively quickly (compared to the pace at which nations operate) due to the inherent instability of the concept.

Comment: Most of the other answers can be summarized with this. Capitalism, Socialism, Merchantilism... all these systems are simply ways to balance the competing demands of consumers and producers. Socialism puts command and control in the government and they cannot afford any mistakes. Because they own everything, if they fail the whole country fails. Capitalism is distributed. Decisions are spread throughout the market and communicate via prices, but a failing business just pulls itself down, not the whole country. That's the difference.

Comment: Two things of note - first and foremost is human nature.  We have both a greedy trait as well as a fairness trait.  Some greed is ok, too much is not.  Second, group size is one of the dominant factors in a working socialistic/communistic community.  Keep each village small and producing only one item. Trade with other communities for the other needs.  If you want to build widget A instead of B, move to that village.  Growth is the part that must be managed - as it is going to be for all countries in the coming decades here on Earth.

Comment: @ZoeyBoles "but a failing business just pulls itself down, not the whole country." Considering the numbers of banks that have had to bailed out by Governments in order to avoid the whole country defaulting, I'm not so sure about this being a positive of Capitalism anymore.

Comment: @SGR Its fair to say that the USA is not an *ideal* capitalist country.  "Ideal" capitalism has a laundry list of issues as well (primarily dealing with monopolies).  It's really all about achieving a balance.  History merely shows that the balance is easier to achieve with a free market.

Comment: @CortAmmon Why did you assume I was talking about the USA? Plenty of other capitalist countries have had to bail out their banks.

Comment: @SGR Forgive me, I'm a US citizen myself, and when you talk about "the number of banks" I made an assumption based on volume.  Please amend my statement to replace "USA" with "{insert country name here}", because the statement is true for 100% of countries which exist and have ever existed.  You can plug any country name in you like.  Plugging in Russia or China may yield to rather obvious claims, though.

Comment: @SGR banking in most countries is not a "separate enterprise." They hold a vast majority of the private debt in countries with huge amounts of public debt, and therefore a failing bank would cause securities to default up the tree.  It's exactly the type of top-down interconnectedness I was talking about. Smaller banking type institutions, like credit unions, which are directly responsible to their customers, weathered the storms just fine because they weren't so interconnected with the government.

Comment: @SGR Do you know what happens when you can force people to accept a state currency, no matter what? The modern banking system. People would have abandoned the dollar long before if it wasn't enforced by the government (and indeed, many attempted to do exactly that, and were shut down by force). It doesn't help that the inflation rate is utterly absurd, with loans being accepted as securities *for other loans*! In a free-market banking system, this quickly caused the bank to lose all business as their money became worthless - with state money, you don't have a choice.

Comment: *"Generally speaking economists and philosophers have found that socialism is an unstable equilibrium. It is constantly being disrupted by the nature of humans, and energy must be continuously spent maintaining it, or it falls apart. The larger the group, the more rapidly it falls off of this ideal."* - How does this differ from every other economic policy?

Comment: @SGR When government interference causes problems in mixed economies, don't blame the capitalist side of that mix.

Answer (score 21):

The basic unit of economic organization is the [Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporation#History).  This is a non-person eintity that can own goods, make agreements, and the like.

Historically, creating such a corporation required government assent.

Smaller organizations, like partnerships, are sort of like them as well.

Modern "Western" economies have a mixture of privately owned corporations, publicly owned corporations, state corporations, nations, non-profit corportations (which are not owned) of various kinds, etc.

I could interpret your meaning as stating the privately owned and publicly owned corporations don't exist.

Examples of such an organizations engaging in commercial purposes is Ikea, most national postal services, central and regional banks.

Now, in the past half-century, there was a massive economic war between "Capitalist" and "Communist" states, and the "Capitalist" states won.  Nations that did not ally with the "Capitalist" states where economically isolated, invaded, attacked, overthrown and destroyed by the winners of this war.

Despite this, some "Socialist" economies have persisted and flourished better than similar nearby "Capitalist" economies.  An example is Cuba, which is richer than the nearby island of Haiti and Dominican Republic (both halves!) despite being both invaded and under economic sanctions from the nearby super power economy (USA).

Corporations themselves almost universally operate as "Socialist" organizations within themselves -- Command Economies.  And there are Corporations whose size exceeds that of many nations.

That isn't to say there aren't horrible traps that Socialist centrally planned economies fall into.

Corporations avoid them through a number of ways.  They aren't the primary power, so their rulers must obey the rules of the state in which they are embedded.  This prevents them from going off-the-rails in power-centralization and protection (the dictator trap, where you turn state power into an engine of protecting the current set of rulers).

As they are relatively small, they often have competition.  Their ability to use their power to crush their competition is limited by the state they are embedded in; which means even strong corporations can eventually be outmaneuvered and fail if they stop generating excess value efficiently.

Newly large capitalist corporations almost always have recently successfully generated a whole pile of surplus value in order to grow.  Inertia keeps them doing what they have been doing, with minor corrections (their correction process was also possibly successful at smaller scales).

Over time they'll drift.  If they remain long, they almost always have a natural monopoly they have managed to corner.  They now drift, protected against competition to some extent by their monopoly power.  Sometimes they drift into being really inefficient; that is when competition can grow and threaten them.  Sometimes they drift into being more efficient.

Cross-transfer of corporate culture occurs, where what other successful corporations are doing is imported via business school graduates, hiring workers from their businesses, etc.  This is another source of culture drift, almost unavoidable if a business wants to grow at a fast pace.

And then they die.  They are torn apart into their assets, and new Corporations claim their "territory".

States could do much the same thing, but traditionaly States "death" involves violent war, revolution, and a lot more destruction than Corporate "death".

So one approach would be to invent an authority that prevents overly violent "death" of States, and prevents them from going into the trap of protecting the ruler's interests against the interest of the State or the (entire) People.

Another would be to point out that the advantages Corporations have over States is mostly long term.  In the short term, it is perfectly plausible for a medium-large "Socialist" state to function.  The Soviet Union went from an agricultural economy to one capable of defeating the German Empire and then holding off the most powerful industrialized nation for a half-century in a few decades under a centrally planned economy.

Another approach is to solve the problem with information.  The theoretical advantage markets have over planning is that markets solve pricing problems better.  A genius economist with modern computers *might* be plausibly able to solve the pricing problem without markets.

Doing so accidentally would easily be reasonable, and sustaining it for a while as well.

The biggest problems against such an experiment in our world is both the extreme risk that it would fail (and cause untold suffering), the violent reaction of the capitalist western economies to such an experiemnt, and the fact that this doesn't prevent the "protect the king" dictatorship trap.

Comment: Good answer beside the information problem. No genious  economist and no kind of computer no matter how strong could solve the pricing problem without a market. Soviets already tried that with Leonid Kantorovich linear programming. The problem is that information is distributed  and not given to the planner. You are dealing with society full of people who are both complex and interact on even more complex ways. You can't optimize what you don't know, market could https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBYzvPbIFNw

Comment: @slob they tried that prior to our current sensor density.  We can literally track everything everyone looks at, consumes, and where thry go, and get a real time approximation of their emotional response at this point.  It is unlikely that it would work, but it is not proven it could not.  You need plausibility, not certainty.

Comment: Even if we hooked up every human being with cameras & other sensors we don't have a clue what that data means. The current AI pinnacle is classifying images  & playing GO. We still don't have a clue how the brain works. Until we do I suggest we stick with the market. Everything else is science fiction at least for near future.

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski the "market" doesn't have a clue how the brain works, either. And it can't even play GO! Only 5% of the world's money exists as real coins or paper money. That could not be said during the 30s and 40s. The market *IS* computers nowadays. Hell, high frequency trading, trading done only by computers, makes up 75% of all trading done in the US. These programs even read the news and make trading decisions based on it. And as AI improves they are only going to get better. Your idea that markets 'don't know' is spurious at best.

Comment: @Shane I know a thing or two about high frequency training & deep learning, they're as far from managing the economy as was Leonid Kantorovich Linear Programming . The market doesn't give a damn how the brain works nor it should, it's through the pricing mechanism that true signals are revealed and that can't be done through any AI in the near future. As long as there is human society with human needs & scarce resources that need to be allocated nothing invented so far beats markets.

Comment: If markets get along fine without knowing how the brain works, claiming that other things won't work because they don't know how the brain works is a logical failure. Claiming that networks and computers don't have the needed data when they actually keep track of all of the data to begin with is a truly bizarre statement to make. Claiming that because something didn't work once nearly a century ago, therefore it won't work ***ever***, is absolute foolishness. Maybe you are right and markets are just the bestest thing ever (Haha, no) but your arguments about it suck.

Answer (score 17):

### A completely socialist country is possible as long as your neighbors aren't capitalists

As kingledion mentioned in his [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/64459/10364), before 1500, it was possible to have a completely socialized/nationalized system.  Prior to 1500, the marriage of religion, economic power and monopoly on violence hadn't yet broken down.  When all countries operate with nationalized industries, they are on equal footing.  However, as soon as someone comes up with capitalism, all those nationalized industries and the countries that depend on them will start to lose.

Most of what keeps capitalistic systems so functional is the inherent competition in free-markets.  Anyone with the capital can start a competitor to a incumbent company and eat their lunch.  Clayton Christensen's [Innovators Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Innovator's_Dilemma) talks about this kind of situation extensively.  Any company in a free-market that fails to eliminate waste, cut expenses and increase profits will eventually go out of business.  In a socialist country, this kind of competition is either impossed by legislation (which can be cheated by legal manuvering or backroom deals) or not at all.  In general, competition in socialized systems is social competition ("who do I know that can get me a sweet deal...") vs free-markets systems ("can I make a product/service that will sell better than the other guy's")

Because of the lack of pressure to be efficient, the nationalized industries will tend to become more inefficient over time.  Capitalist industries tend to get more efficient over time because of competition.  As long as the socialized country doesn't have to compete with anyone else, it should be okay.

"An economy that doesn't suck" is inherently comparitive.  A nationalized economy that benefits everyone is better than no industry.

Comment: Does it mean that capitalist industries are better at competition, without having to be necessarily more efficient? Or am I reading this in a wrong way?

Comment: Any company, socialist or capitalist, will be as efficient as the environment demands.  In a system described by the OP, the pressures to be efficient are low.  In a free-market economy, pressures to be efficient and therefore profitable can be (though are not always) extremely high

Comment: This here is a good example of some broad generalizations.

Comment: capitalist systems do not necessarily become more efficient over time - cartels and monopolies can emerge and basically institutionalize the then-current power balance (Happens, when the state can not enforce anti-trust laws). A state-owned situation where different branches compete with each other and vie for recognition by the central government could be just as efficient as a market without government participation. As long as new market participants have a reasonable chance, all systems could tend to efficiency.

Comment: @Chieron, you're absolutely right.  Institutionalized companies in free-market capitalism or socialized economies are perhaps inevitable but will be no more efficient than they need to be.  I agree.

Comment: I think most South Korean people are satisfied of the state-owned train network, whereas traveling by train in the US is notoriously a pain in the ass. You may say that the train system in the US degenerated because traveling by car or by plane is more efficient. But efficient for who?

Comment: @Taladris more efficient for everyone - trains are fantastic for cargo and relatively worse for passengers. By far the *best* solution, in terms of cost, convenience, and environmental impact, is to optimize the train system for freight and not for passengers. But when you don't care about actual outcomes, just making a feel-good soundbite to use for political reasons (because government optimizes for politics rather than outcomes), then go ahead and make shiny pretty trains for passenger service (heavily subsidized by taxes to hide the cost).

Comment: @pluckedkiwi: what are your alternatives for passengers? Cars? Not better in the environmental and safety aspects. In terms of convenience, if  you have lived in a big city and experience traffic jam, you know how inconvenient cars can be.

Comment: @Taladris I've had 3 hour commutes due to traffic, but cars are still better for nearly everyone (hence the popularity). The comparative environmental impact is not that significant (cars have improved since the 70s and are still improving) and often favors cars (trains are not full both ways at all times). Point to point transport is always better and the cost (both financial and environmental) is comparable when you include construction and maintenance (funny how transit systems "forget" about those costs). Rail is fantastic for heavy slow transport - not so much for people.

Answer (score 13):

It is worth looking at some examples of countries that attempted at one point or another to introduce some form of market socialism. 
For instance, in China 50% of GDP is still generated by SOEs, and it is mostly the large companies that are state-owned.

You may also want to look at other countries with a large SOE sector, such as Russia, Malaysia, UAE, Saudi Arabia, Indonesia, India or Brazil. Some are relatively successful, many are not and struggle with ineffective management and corruption.The biggest issue is the introduction of effective governance and the creation of incentives that are similar to those faced by privately-owned companies.

The most interesting example is Singapore, where, although the economy is mostly composed of small and medium enterprises, pretty much all the large ones are SOEs. Singapore is considered to be a very successful case of how the state can manage SOEs well. Corporations linked to the government account for around 50% of the stock market valuation in Singapore.

Comment: +1 for Singapore. I don't know what sort of -ism it is. Rather unique, and we don't yet know how it will fare once its founders pass away.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, 
A Post-Scarcity society can be purely socialist because it no longer needs motivated humans to fill all of the roles in the economy.  With AI driven robots handling all of the mining, farming, manufacturing, distribution, and everything else, each human citizen can have a life of leisure with all of the material wealth that they can ever dream of.
See [Cory Doctorow's Down and Out in the Magic Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_and_Out_in_the_Magic_Kingdom) for a good example of what such a society would look like.

Comment: There is still an economy at play, though, and there will always be scarcity. Who is in charge of deciding how many robots to make? Is it more important use steel to build robots right now or cars, or buildings? How much wheat should be produced, should dairy be working towards cheese or milk production? In a capitalist society, these decisions are decided by purchases and price, in the society you describe, it'd be committees deciding allocation of resources, and this always ends in warehouses full of toilet paper.

Comment: So combine this answer with @user3644640's answer above, where a benevolent AI makes all the resource allocation decisions.

Answer (score 8):

From personal memories, Hungary in the seventies seems to be a good match.
The question specifies a particular decade, so the long term sustainability and unchanging political system may not be relevant.

Big city: Budapest with two million people, check.

Well maintained buildings, er, needs a local party secretary with good taste and then no problem. Certain parts were nice, others not so much. A lot of old residential buildings had WW2 scars even later, but many new (70's era) buildings were erected.

No queues for basic food & clothing, in national store chains.

Cars were those normal in the Eastern block, but they were all imports so long queues existed. People waited sometimes ten years after submitting the request before they could receive the car, then request the next to have it in another ten years.

Small non-family ventures (GMK) appeared in the 80-ies and then the private sector gradually increased as the Soviets looked elsewhere. In the 70-ies this may not be in the picture.

Corporation management included a representative of the Party who was influential. The workers not so much.

Comment: Yes, kind of communism but the soft version of it with some freedoms and a large pool of talented workers. That could have worked out at least to some degree.

Comment: Same goes pretty much for Czechoslovakia in the 70's and 80's pretty much thought of as the shining beacon of the iron curtain. (At least by us in the west.)
While it wasn't exactly a picnic it was by no means the Soviet Union or DDR.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_communist_Czechoslovakia

Answer (score 7):

Just look at the list of [countries with large ratios of tax revenue to GDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tax_revenue_as_percentage_of_GDP) and you find at the top of the list: *Denmark, Belgium, France, Sweden, Cuba, Finnland, Norway* with about 45-50% percent government income (or spending) of total GDP. Depending on your definition of socialism this might not yet fit, but indeed these countries are probably amonst the most social in the world and quite successful economically they are too.

Depending on how socialistic you want your country to be, take some traits of these and then mix them together.

For example give them:

- a strong political, philosophical tradition of egalite (the notion that all men (and women) are equal) like in France
- strong unions demanding a share of the profit like in France
- a good educational system like in Denmark, Sweden, Cuba, Finnland
- lots of natural resources like in Norway
- money from supranational organizations to build their headquarters there like in Belgium
- a superb and free healthcare system like in Cuba (and Denmark and ...)
- peaceful neighbours like in Denmark, Sweden, Norway,...
- incredible transparency like the public tax declarations in Sweden
- a very rich society where everyone has plenty of everything like in Norway (so nobody is really unsatisfied)

So much for real world examples, now for some fictious properties:

- draconic laws and efficient persecution could eliminate corruption
- effective taxation could eliminate waste (like taxing luxuries very high and useful stuff very low)
- just incredible luck with choosing superb (incorruptible) leaders (outstanding personality, clever, charismatic, beloved) - sometimes you are just lucky
- some kind of philosophy/religion that gives everyone the idea that the community must work together and everybody has the duty to give
- a strong principle of subsidiarity, so people vote regularly on everything they are responsible for (what should be researched next, which motorways should be built, what kind of cars should be produced,...), make the unions and party actually desirable organizations, a place where people find together

This all might result in a socialistic country like none we know and it might work or might not work, but given a bit of luck, at least modest economic success should be guaranteeable, you just need the right people for it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it needs almost perfect resource management or some quasi-free markets. It needs a system that is guarding the administration and itself, by for example having multiple divisions that enforce the policies on every governmental body, including each other.

It is hard, and no system has ever succeed. With technology a super intelligent AI that oversees could make it work.

Comment: It's impossible even with super intelligent AI, you must use market prices to reveal hidden human preferences. Check Mises Economic calculation problem https://infogalactic.com/info/Economic_calculation_problem

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski *you must use market prices to reveal hidden human preferences.* - I like that, lol. How about just telling what you like and what you not like :) "you can" or "we use" but "must" as it is the only way looks like a religion :)

Comment: @MolbOrg If you want efficiently allocate scarce resources you MUST use prices "The truth is, the only way to determine how much someone will pay for something is to put it up for sale, and see how many people actually buy it."  https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2004/12/15/camels-and-rubber-duckies/

Comment: Who finds the logical gap between the two statements by @slobodan.blazeski ? :-)

Comment: @MolbOrg There is no other mechanism that so far we as humanity invented that serves that purpose better. You might decide to allocate scarce resource in some other way: by need which is done in the family, or to your party donors which is called cronyism, through central planning like Gosplan. But all of this fared poorly. No matter how smart you AI is it must use prices. Unless its also omnipresent and could read minds.

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski I have a lot to say in response, but I will say only one, the thing I agree with you, so far we haven't tested a much better system yet, at the scale current system works, and as well known as current one.

Comment: If there are hidden human preferences then the AI isn't smart enough. When it can fully simulate the humans then it can spin up N copies of them, check which allocation works best. In fact, this may be happening right now. :-)

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski Thats where the quasi-free markets come. The consumers did have cash at the communism. It gives some flexibility. The object of production side is simply to maximise the value of the products. The preferences are not really too much of problem, because they can be sampled by simply asking. If an agent would lie, then the allocation would get worse and thus they have no reason to lie.

Comment: @MolbOrg If you invent a better mechanism the Nobel prize is yours, in the meantime  market is the worst form of allocation, except for all the others  that have been tried.

Comment: @user3644640 Actually it is unsolvable problem with our current knowledge and technology. Unless by solving you mean ignoring human preferences. Like when USSR bought all their lipstick in exactly same color & shade, Moscow ladies weren't too pleased to say the least. But for the planer the quota was achieved, every women over 16 has X amount of lipstick, the plan is achieved 100% comrade. And no asking doesn't help because people lie, read the http://bit.ly/2hwL3Ut to get idea why especially the part when guy tries to impress the lady. Without some big breakthrough you MUST use prices.

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski it's not that complicated. Mechanism design has the solution. Asking about preferences **before** production means that agents will want the optimal production quantities so that their value is optimised. If the agent does not know what other people have said, then they cannot compensate that. The only reasonable solution is to tell the real preference because it is guaranteed to bring the outcome closer to the outcome, the agent would prefer. You gave example how USSR failed to serve micro-segments. It is one of the problem of monolithic system.

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski no, tnx, I'll just take the money

Comment: @MolbOrg :) You have to earn them first

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski I have to figure out the system, after that, all your money is my as once Terminator have said.

Answer (score 4):

## No

Centrally planned economies have universally been a disaster. They're unable to respond to local requirements and market pressures fast enough to be useful.

Nationalising universal infrastructure like water and power and the rail companies, all perfectly reasonable. You could even consider nationalising the automotive industry if you want everyone to drive really boring cars. The worst you'll get out of this is epic inefficiency.

However there's really no point nationalising a tea shop or surf school, all of which will come under your current heading. Local business needs to remain locally owned and run, responding to local needs and environment. A government owned tea shop would look the same as every other tea shop in the country and end up with all the wrong stock for local tastes.

The state should only get involved a company which is a (near) national monopoly or nationally critical infrastructure.

---

As a note relating to ownership and management. Since, as everyone knows, property is theft, "ownership" in a socialist world means "control".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50046/discussion-on-answer-by-separatrix-socialist-country-with-good-economy).

Comment: Local requirements aren't a problem if you get a more homogenous populace. I recommend structuring sci-fi socialism around a very strong eugenics program with intense social programming. "Brave New World" comes to mind.

Comment: There's no reason shared ownership means nationalising.  A tea shop could be a member coop or be owned and run by the village council.  The tea served by the library is technically served by a socialist enterprise.

Comment: @gerrit, I'm not sure why you're talking about shared ownership? There's no reference to it in question or answer

Comment: @Separatrix The very first word in the title of the question says "socialist", which, by definition, means shared ownership of the means of production.  Socialism does not imply a planned economy and a free market does not imply capitalism.

Comment: @gerrit, when I answered the question it only mentioned government ownership of anything over 10 people, it's softened somewhat since then

Answer (score 2):

I think your description leaves a loop hole that not only makes this possible but also transforms your world into a pseudo-capitalistic system.

Much like anything running a business is a skill some people are very good, others not so much.

In your proposed framework really good business people would build a business to the allowable limit and then stop.  Sort of.  While they might not own the business they might also run the business of their friend as well as their own.  The friend and the good business owner would split profits.  The friend would benefit by having money for nothing, and the business owner would be able to grow a second business and quite possibly the first as the two might compliment each other.

Then how many associates could the good business owner repeat this process?  In effect he would form a conglomerate of small family businesses, and presumably have a large income.

Comment: This actually happens  quite often when regulation is onerous "Why so many French firms are stuck at 49 employees" https://www.aeaweb.org/research/charts/french-firms-50-employees but it kicks in after certain number of employees

Comment: Similar things happen in the US.  One company I know of does design work for the government.  If the company with the contract does the design, the IP belongs to the government.  If that same company hires a third company to do the same work the third company owns the design work.  Guess contractors form two companies and they will own the IP forever.  Different kind of thing, but similar loophole finding skills.

Answer (score 2):

Make it **small**, **religious**, and **unappealing to foreign aggressors**.

Let's work backwards from the problems of real attempts at socialism:

1. Lack of incentives discourages hard work: You mention "upper middle class" so it sounds like you're OK with some financial incentives, but social prestige is just as motivating. Give them a traditional religion (maybe even an interpretation of Christianity) where charity is the strongest ideal, so people aren't angry about others "leeching" of their work. Make the country small enough that people can earn a reputation for helping the country, and the critical inventors and managers can become celebrities.
2. Central planning is hard: Hayek was right, markets rock. But you don't need everything run by a single 5 year plan. Break the economy into manageable chunks (Amazon has 300k employees and is still dynamic), and make the country overall small enough that there are a manageable number of them. Give the people a few different options (like 4 independently managed but government owned fast food chains) and let them allocate resources.
3. Lack of investment in consumer products: Both the Soviet Union and current China are trying to build armies that directly compete with that of the largest economy on Earth. That takes an incredible amount of money and necessitates investment in heavy industry over keeping the people happy. Make them unappealing to foreign aggression by making the world safe (like modern day Europe), or making the country lack in strategic value or be naturally defensible (like Switzerland).
4. Corruption: This is hardly unique to socialism, but destroyed the Venezuelan experiment and is common in centralized economies. But it's mitigated with a religious/social more against opulence and a way to remove those in a position to profit from corruption. Let the monastic priests kick the crooks out.

Bonus: Give them a head start. The GDP per capita of the areas that would become the USSR was only 1488 on the eve of the revolution compared to 5301 in the US. Even if they had they'd matched US GDP growth until today, they'd still be 3.5x poorer. If the situation was reversed, the socialist country could grow slower and still be relatively more prosperous.

EDIT: Added 4.

Comment: The stipulation of religion is good. I think that the Jewish kibbutzes were probably the most successful socialist societies. You would need extremely high social cohesion for socialism to work, and religion provides that to some extent. Religion could discourage people from free-riding.

Answer (score 2):

### It's not impossible

But it should be understood that Karl Marx's original vision was not that Communism would be efficient, but that it could be adopted in a post-scarcity economy and it wouldn't matter if it wasn't efficient.

The key to getting Communism right is to get the post scarcity economy first, then switch to Communism so everyone has a slice of the pie. Actual Communist countries have made the switch without the post scarcity economy and found that the existing scarcity got worse and there wasn't enough pie to go around.

Socialism in general is like this. Morally appealing, but expensive. You take what you can afford.

Comment: James notice that communism as a political ideology is both stateless and prior to Karl Marx (that notably described Marxism). Socialism itself (again as a political ideology) requires democratic control of means of production. Due to many countries calling themselves Communist ..., Socialist ..., Republic of ..., Democratic ..., United ..., has been more of a propaganda operation than an factual description of what the country really is. For example Social Democracy (i.e. most of Europe) is no more than a reinforcement that a party follows a Socialist philosophy under a Democracy.

Answer (score 1):

What history has taught us is that a system with a wasteful controlling class, a communist party, a dictator, a royal family, will indeed leave the lower classes poor and wanting.

Most people forget how wasteful the current capitalist system is and how many people are left poor and wanting. How many homeless people are there in the US? How many people have lost everything when last bubble bursted?

A friend of mine told me in the late eighties that a plan economy could not work because the giant matrices you'll have to calculate to set prices and production so that you could reduce waste. It would take so long to calculate what next years production should be, that next year would have gone and many other next years with it before you got the result.

That was true then, today you could just fire up an array of a few thousands of high grade graphics cards and be done with it in a few weeks.

And to beat the current capitalist system it does not have to be optimal, it only has to be decent.

Comment: Your friend has not made a career in [Data assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_assimilation).  The matrices that get inverted every 3 hours to produce weather forecasts are ***huge***.

Answer (score 1):

Another close-enough example can be Turkey 1923-1946.

State ownership of major industries was not as absolute as you require, but it was close. The country was founded on the ashes of the Ottoman empire, severely depleted of capital after 500 years of continuous warfare, often on the losing side.

The ethnic minorities that comprised the majority of the upper middle class were either living outside the newly drawn borders, immigrated, "exchanged", or purged. Therefore, the ruling founder of the country, Mustafa Kemal, adopted "statism" and started a 25 year period of the state building and running all kinds of industrial enterprises from sugar factories to foundries to textile mills.

Private enterprise was not illegal but very few private citizens had the necessary capital. Feudal "lords" in the countryside continued to own large swathes of land, though; agriculture was not cooperative-ized (These landowners eventually supported a more conservative, capitalist movement from 1946 onwards).

This country supported exactly 1 city of 1M+ (Istanbul) where quality of life was very reasonable for the middle class compared to the rest of Europe. Buildings were not only in good state of repair but were admired all over the continent fo their architecture.

However, this being 1930s, private automobile ownership would not be at the level you need.

Source: My ancestors lived there during the time period described.

Answer (score 0):

To make this stable in slightly longer term, instead of everyone starving themselves if they don't work, in the laziest way, everyone should have some inherent high income and expense, which cancels out so they have the net income similar to the rest of the world.

At first I thought of making a group of scientists to declare independence in Antarctica or even Mars. But that doesn't seem to satisfy your criteria.

But some much simpler models might work too, for example some oil field near some extreme environment. The expense could be explained by the extreme environment. But the problem is, if humans didn't have modern technologies when they first arrive there, so they still have chances to form a new country, how did they survive? The income could be from the oil field. But why isn't it owned by the leader of the first group of people discovering it? And many young people may not think an oil field could prove all their value. Why don't they want to leave there? The answers might not be straightforward, but I think they should be all possible.

The nearest thing in the modern world might be the space station. It's unlikely anyone will charge the astronauts for their expenses, even if the expenses are not for their main mission. And it is expensive to launch all the resources they require. The only difference beside not being an independent country is that they relies on the earth and cannot generate income themselves.

Many companies in capitalist countries could operate in similar ways. It's just a way to isolate them to a specific location and prevent them dealing with anyone else after their jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The power isn't allowed to be to concentrated and retained indefinitly, otherwise you will end up with defacto oligarchies or dictatorship. Make it a multiparty system (maybe each party representing different interests, like internet interests, scientific interests, technical interests, nature preserving interests, production interests in general, policy interests, system failure-fix interests).

The country needs (not only theoretical, but practically) guranteed free speech and free journalism.

People need to really have influence and there need to be anti-corruption mechanisms that immediatly imprison/fire anyone not reporting a bribe attempt or taking a bribe. You can use randomly appointed citizens which serve as short term inspectors as control instance here, for the important tasks. The control should be without any holes, so that inbetween inspections no corruption can take place.

If you have a high focus on scientific method in the goverment and control mechanisms that prevent capitalistic failures and corruption, and potentially give some incentives for work, like a public reputation system or privilege system that gives you quicker access (other still get access but require longer time) to luxury goods, then I can easily see a non-corrupt goverment of any kind to be more efficent than any other system.

Because lets face it UDSSR, failed because of a static high power with non-shifting goverments, which were highly corrupt. This is also todays russian problem were police is still corrupt and power is still static.

Answer (score 0):

What about Yugoslavia itself? Did you consider it as an example?

I think it can be definitely considered a socialist country. In Belgrade has over a million citizens. [Novi Beograd, 1980. Isn't it a beautiful example of communist architecture?](https://www.flickr.com/photos/26983280@N00/16781027944)

They had these "famous" Yugo cars and I think buildings were pretty well maintained, at least according to the pictures of the 70s you can find. 
The overall standard of living surely wasn't as bad as in the USSR since it was an open country, people could easily leave it. In fact many did, there has always been a strong Yugoslavian immigration in Germany and Switzerland. But if things down there were as bad as in the USSR, almost everyone would have left the country (like many people wanted in the GDR, for example). It was also a quite popular holiday destination for western-Europeans. [Here are some pictures of a resort close to Dubrovnik, in the 1980s and what's left of it today](http://www.adriaforum.com/kroatien/threads/zupa-dubrovacka-01-kupari-%E2%80%93-der-verfall-einer-touristischen-hochburg.57108/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. Please take a look at the worldbuilding tour and the help center on how to write good answers (http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help).

Would you please write some facts about Yugoslavia, why this country should be considered as a good example (and please, not just a link to Wikipedia).

Comment: @Frostfyre I think this post attempts to answer the question, but it would be great if Tobi could add more details about why 1970s-1980s Yugoslavia's economy could be considered 'good.'

Comment: @kingledion At the time, the answer consisted of just the first two sentences.

Comment: @Frostfyre No harm in deleting your from-review comment if it no longer applies. Remember, comments are ephemeral.

Comment: @kingledion Yugoslavia was much richer (10X-20X higher living standard) then former Eastern block countries, partly due to less socialism, and because it got special treatment (access to markets) & credits from the West. However in the 80's the economy was already in serious trouble, with lack of credit, jobs and competitiveness.  So it could serve as a good setting, but only because economic & diversity problems were hidden under the rug.

Comment: I think an important reason were also the thousands of workers abroad who regularly sent money (in foreign currency!) to their families and relatives in Yugoslavia.

Comment: Together with thousands of (western) tourist they brought millions of Deutsche Mark, British Pounds, Austrian Schilling, Swiss and French Francs and other "hard", western currencies to Yugoslavia. 
This was a big difference to many other socialist countries, like Eastern Germany, that always lacked of sufficient funds in western currencies.

Answer (score 0):

## Sure.

For completely mysterious reason, the other answers missed the most obvious example of a large socialist country with economy not just good but booming, about tripling in the 25 years between 1945 and 1970:
[image]

This disproves, on empirical grounds, any theoretical argument that "Socialism *cannot* work under *any* circumstances". A [conventional wisdom](https://www.thecrimson.com/article/1960/10/17/professor-predicts-soviet-union-growth-will/) in 50s and 60s was that USSR was soon to overtake the US (much like Japan a bit later and then China still later, which also never happened).

A common argument against socialism is that later USSR failed to transition to high income, collapsing instead. While the socialist economy inefficiencies surely might have contributed to that, it would be hard to prove that they played a non-negligible role, let alone decisive. First, the USSR military spending was about 15% of GDP, which is *huge* (as we know, the current NATO target is 2% and many members fail to meet even that); add to that the financing of the "sphere of influence". Second, it had a political system discouraging open discussion, and ruled by indoctrinated, incompetent, and, towards the end, very old apparatchiks. Third, the collapse happened partly for political reasons having little to do with socialism (e.g., national movements in republics). Fourth, it was poorly integrated into the world economy, again partly for political reasons. These and other factors seem more important than the selection in a local tee shop.

Then again, the actual question concerns 70's, when Soviet economy was still growing. Undeniably, the quality of life and consumerism was lagging far behind the developed capitalist nations. However, it's again hard to prove that it was because socialism could never deliver. Socialism delivered growth; it was a political decision to channel it into tanks and warplanes rather than cars. Since you mention cars, passenger car production was negligible until 1970, but then, once a decision was made, the production *quadrupled in four years* to more than 1 million cars a year. I see no a priori reasons why the decision could not have been made in 1960 instead, and why 1 M/y could not be 5 M/y, giving a car to most families by 1970.

In conclusion, yes, it's absolutely plausible, if your socialist country has no ambition to rule half of the world, does not (have to) spend 15% GDP on the military, and consequently makes earlier decision to emphasize consumer goods.

Comment: This graph has been adjusted using some very dishonest statistics.  For starters, it crops off the massive collapse in GDP seen between 1910 and 1920 when the Communist takeover happened and thier per capita dropped to less than half of what it was.  When you include this lose caused by the Communist transition, they experienced a 410% growth, not the 1000% growth this chart seems to be suggesting.   In this same time frame, most Western Countries grew 500-650%.

Comment: Also the average per Capita GDP of Western countries during this time period was consistently 2-4 times as high as Russia; so, showing that they almost kept up with inflation ignores the fact that thier per capita was consistently terrible.  This was not a booming economy at all.  They started off bad, and stayed bad, the illusion of growth here is just inflation.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, you seem to be confusing inflation and growth. The former is money losing value; the latter is increase in output, due to increase in productivity (or employment rate). This graph is adjusted to 2011 dollars, so has nothing to do with inflation at all. Also, you seem to claim that USSR almost kept up with the western growth rate and, at the same time, did not grow. Both cannot be true simultaneously.

Comment: I compared the graph to another source that includes many countries, and did not claim to adjust for inflation, and found the growth rate too similar to believe that this is not just a graph of inflation.  That is unless my other source was also adjusted for inflation, and just failed to mention it.  If the later is the case then the interpretation of the data is that Russia's economy grew, but was much weaker and grew slower than its Western counterparts.

Comment: That said, there are a LOT of ways to measure inflation and compare wealth: relative income, relative buying power, relative cost of living, etc.  So, depending on what metric you use, you can either see a pattern of growth or stagnation over time.  But any way you compare it, during any given year, Western Nations were out producing Russia per capita by a huge margin.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, no serious economist or historian denies that USSR economy grew, by any metric, about as fast as the West, except for devastating war periods. Purely demographically, it went from about 75% rural, non-mechanized agriculture to 75% urban, industrial economy, which has vastly higher productivity. Comparison at any given year is irrelevant since if the growth rate is the same, the difference is entirely due to the lower starting point.

Comment: It is not a different starting place because under the aristocracy, they were not much different from Western Europe. When they switched to communism (which is the variable of interest here), they quickly regressed to ~1/3 of thier potential and stayed at ~1/3 of thier potential for 70ish years.  Yes, they urbanized and researched new technologies, but they suffered from motivational and organizational issues that plagued thier society with inefficiency regardless of how many new tools and technologies they adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No. Maybe.

Redistribution requires centralization, centralization is faulty, thus redistribution always produces a faulty system. In addition redistribution often destroys complexity- and complexity is the most important production factor in a industrial economy (without we would all starve to death).

Then again, capitalism degrading to a oligarchy (centralization) becomes flawed and faulty too. So the optimal system, which is partially communist, would be a loop between the two extremes.

As in, a oligarchy gets auto-broken up by social turmoil, gets redistributed (without destroying the complexity) and then the whole thing returns to capitalism without ever going through the centralized state phase. Its basically a emulation of what civilwar/social unrest or external war/conquest do to a society without the unrest/conquest + complexity degradation.

Its basically a combustion engine, with a restructuring of oligarchs as soon as they attack the engine. Of course there you encounter the problematic part of that plan. The individual.

Individuals may invest into "tribes" more then into a functioning of the system splitting up tribes or limiting there ability to move. So the individual would need to be manipulated to partially act against its own instinctive interest. Be it rich or poor.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to consider Poland. Similarly to Hungary, Poland had such kind of economy as you need. But you should remember, that Poland got big debts and credits at that time. As a consequence, your economy will collapse at the end of 70ths.

Comment: Poland wasn't in a good economic situation after WW2...